# Maintenance plan for creating transaction log backups

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have a database that is set to the 'Full' recovery model, and I'm creating a maintenance plan to backup the Transaction Log every 15 minutes. A full backup is then taken once every 24 hours.

I was wondering: will the maintenance plan for the transaction logs create a lot of different files every 15 minutes, or will it by default append to the same file for 24 hours?

Also: what is preferred? I couldn't find anything on this subject (or maybe I was Googling the wrong words).

Thanks for any pointers anyone can give me.

EDIT: I also see that the checkmark "Verify backup integrity" is OFF by default. Is there a risk with turning it on? It seems to be that it should be on by default, so is there a reason for not using this?

Comment: I'd recommend against maintenance plans entirely. There are totally free scripts that do a much better job of things: ola.hallengren.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to read up on the concept of Transaction Log Backups in the following Microsoft Technet Article: [SQL Server - Understanding SQL Server Backups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.07.sqlbackup.aspx)

If you set up a maintenance plan that creates a transaction log backup of all your user databases, then the backup job will create a *.TRN (default extension) file for each database and for each scheduled run.

Depending on the retention period you set in your maintenance plan, you will/can have literally thousands of transaction log backup files (*.trn) in your backup location.

E.g. Backing up a 10 user databases every 15 minutes and leaving the retention period for clean-up to 30 days, will leave you with 28'800 transaction log backup files lying around.

```
10 db * 1 trn/db/15min * 1440 min/d * 30d = 28'800 trn files

db = database
trn = trn backup file
min = minutes
d = day
```

So depending on the size of the databases and the amount of changing data, you could end up needing quite a lot of disk space for your transcation log backups. Then again, having a short retention period in your maintenance plan could result in lower disk space requirements.

Pssst, after reading the Microsoft article, have a look at some alternative backup solutions, like [Ola's Maintenance script](https://ola.hallengren.com) or other alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You will have 1 Tlog backup every 15 minutes per database you have set in the maintenance plan.  In regards to Verify Backup integrity, I would reference this answer for Verify Backup Integrity.

Comment: So, one file per database? Or one file per database every 15 minutes? (in other words, after a few hours, will it flood my folder with different log backups per database, or will it remain one file per database)

Comment: Yes - one file per database every 15 minutes.

Comment: It depends on how you set up your folder structure.  I have my TLogs set up to go into their own database folder for each.  I also have the clean up set to 120 hours so I do not blow the system out.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your follow-up question:

> I also see that the checkmark "Verify backup integrity" is OFF by default. Is there a risk with turning it on? It seems to be that it should be on by default, so is there a reason for not using this?

I'd recommend leaving this off.

[See this related question for a more complete discussion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117028/understanding-the-impact-risk-of-turning-off-verify-backup-integrity-on-sql-ba), but all this does is do a `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` on each backup file immediately after the backup completes, which **doubles your backup job time for very little benefit**.

All a `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` does it ensure that the *backup file can be read off the disk*, which is something that used to be a big deal in the "olden-days" when we backed up straight to flaky tape drives. Your environment might be different than mine, but I haven't backed up to tapes in a decade or more.

It doesn't do anything to validate that the backup is *restorable*, something you can only tell by *doing a test restore* (usually in a test environment).

So leave it off on backups, but make sure that you are occasionally doing full test restores of random backups to make sure they work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will get every 15 minutes a new file with transaction log backup. But such backup strategy can fully your local drive. I'd recommend you to use a third party tool like [SQLBackupAndFTP](https://sqlbackupandftp.com/) of [SqlBak](https://sqlbak.com/) wich can backup your SQL Server databases and delete old backups according to your schedule automatically.

Disclaimer: I am the Marketing Manager for Pranas.NET.

Comment: Alex, please disclose your affiliation to SqlBak when providing links to your company's product in answers, as per the [behavior guidelines](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).