# Changing MaximumErrorCount when executing maintenance plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, maintenance-plans

I have defined a Maintenance Plan in Microsoft SQL Server 2012. It doesn't execute and it says

```
   DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.
 The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure.
 This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors////
```

Where should change it?

Comment: I would suggest you to [move away from maintenance plans](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94385/8783).

Answer (score 2):

Each task in a Maintenance Plan has a variety of options that can be changed by right-clicking the desired task, then selecting the "Properties" option from the context-menu.  As in:

[image]

To allow a task to have multiple errors prior to failing, simply modify the `MaximumErrorCount` property I've highlighted above to some number greater than 1.

Having said that, Maintenance Plans are difficult to manage.

Options I recommend using instead:

- [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com) has a great replacement solution that is extensible and makes management a breeze.
- [MinionWare Backup](http://www.minionware.net/products/backup/) - built by DBAs for DBAs.

Comment: After changing this to a high number, I still did not get any redirected rows to the error table. It just stopped the job, but I would want the job to go on and throw only the erroneous rows out to the error table. My problem was that I casted a number as `AS DECIMAL(4,2))` even though it had to be `AS DECIMAL(5,2))`, see [how to resolve DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78176256/11154841). But such an error should normally just redirect the row to the error table and not stop the job, shouldn't it?

Comment: I would suggest you [ask](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) that as a standalone question; add a link to this question if relevant.  Also, as noted in my answer, I would highly recommend using an alternate solution to maintenance jobs.  They are unreliable, as you're seeing, and operate as a black box that you have no insight into.

Comment: Done at [Can I redirect rows on error in SSIS if the error happens within an "if condition", not while writing the column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78196761/11154841).