# Maintenance Plan on Replication Subscriber

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactional-replication, maintenance

I have seven subscribers to a replicated publication using transactional replication in SQL Server 2012.

Do I treat the subscribers just like a normal database and perform maintenance via a maintenance plan on them - or should they be left alone / treated any differently?

I know that Microsoft recommend backing up subscriber databases as usual, so I presume this would be part of a normal maintenance plan?

Comment: Yes, you should. It is no different than your other DBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I treat the subscribers just like a normal database and perform maintenance via a maintenance plan on them - or should they be left alone / treated any differently?

Yes, subscriber databases should be treated as regular user databases & you should [intelligently perform Index maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) (and [do backups](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) as well) . Infact, [replication does not replicate index maintenance](http://sqlfool.com/2009/01/fragmentation-on-replicated-tables/). Also, [from BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151740.aspx) :

[image]

One suggestion - [please **do not** use maintenance plan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94385/8783) !