# T-SQL Statement Task choose specific database name on server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, maintenance-plans

I try to create a simple T-SQL Statement Task by Sql Server 2014 GUI.

My flow:

- Right click on Maintenance Plan
- Choose Create new Maintenance Plan
- Choose the type (T-SQL Statement Task)
- I add by toolbox an activity for SQL Statement (a simple `SELECT * INTO mytable FROM anothertable`)

Now I want to choose the databases where I want to execute my task.

By property I've changed the `DatabaseSelectionType` to `SPECIFIC` but I haven't any form to choose database.

If I try with another task type (Index maintenance) I can choose the databases.

Surely, I'm wrong in some steps but I don't understand where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My solution** (but in the next days I will try Ola's maint solution).

I've created an empty database with a stored procedure.

This stored procedures call by other involved databases a local stored procedure with the logic.

In the maintenance plan I've added a step as Transact Sql where I call my general SP (on empty database defined before).

And then I've planned the execution for each day.

Answer (score 1):

*Do not rely on GUI .. use TSQL instead :-)*

Many options you have to do your simple task :

- use 3 part naming `SELECT * INTO dbname.schema.mytable FROM dbname.schema.anothertable`
- explicitely use `use dbname; SELECT * INTO mytable FROM anothertable;`
- Use sqlcmd - either sqlcmd.exe or in [SSMS query window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx)
- Use powershell

BTW, [dont use maintenance plans - instead use Ola's maint solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94385/8783)

Comment: Hi, I try to use Ola's maint solution. But other solutions, don't seem for my activity.

Comment: Can you be more specific .. what does not fit ?