# Transaction Log Backup during Index Rebuild and Integrity Maintenance Jobs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, maintenance-plans, performance-tuning

Brent Ozar mentioned there is nothing wrong about conducting transaction log backups during full backups.
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/12/what-happens-to-transaction-log-backups-during-full-backups/

Just inquiring if the same statement applies for maintenance plans below, running transaction log backups during:

(a) Index rebuilds and

(b) DB integrity checks.

I tested this on our system, functionally and cpu%/memory usage, everything seems fine.

I read from article above. I want to ensure same principle applies. "Take log backups during full backups. You can take them and nothing will break...Log backups during full backups won’t hurt anything, and may end up helping things if your full backup fails, and you need to restore something."

Comment: Be cautious when running checkdb and backups together they both with overwhelm the I/O and you might see lot of slowness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul Randal writes about [concurrent backups in his backups myths](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-3030-backup-myths/)

> Myth: 30-04) concurrent log backups are not possible while a full or differential backup is in progress

Index rebuild generates transaction log and so you need to run log backups to keep it trimmed. Make sure you do it in an [intelligent way](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207083/8783) keeping in mind the [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/transaction-log-disk-space-for-index-operations?view=sql-server-2017).

CHECKDB is for determining database corruption. It wont grow your transaction log.