# Log Shipping and Daily Backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, log-shipping, maintenance-plans

My SQL Server 2012 DR setup is a mess. We've had a maintenance plan in place from the beginning that takes a daily full backup, with hourly log backups. Recently, we set up log shipping to an off-site server and it seemed to be working great. The LSBackup job runs every 15 minutes.

I know that I need to change my maintenance plan to Full + Differential, but my question is do I need to remove all log shipping, restore the secondary database from the most recent full backup and then set up log shipping again?

Or, can I pause the LS jobs, to the restore and then restart the LS jobs?

Or, is the secondary server fine an I just need to fix my maintenance plan?

Comment: Why not simply err on the side of caution and redo the log shipping setup after you have corrected the maintenance plans?  At the same time, you can re-verify with the data stakeholders that your RPO of 15 minutes is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Recently, we set up log shipping to an off-site server and it seemed to be working great. The LSBackup job runs every 15 minutes.

You should change the maintenance plan and just take full and diff (if required). Since logshipping is taking log backups every 15 mins, you dont need hourly log backup.

> but my question is do I need to remove all log shipping, restore the secondary database from the most recent full backup and then set up log shipping again?

No since your log shipping is working fine. Just remove additional log backups from maintenance plans since it can break log shipping.

> Or, can I pause the LS jobs, to the restore and then restart the LS jobs?

As a caution, you can pause all the jobs, take a diff backup and then start your log backup, copy and restore jobs one by one.

Just remove the maintenance plan log backup job.

Much better to use [Ola's backup solution rather than using maintenance plans](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/94385/8783).

Comment: They say "no news is good news", but that doesn't count when your secondary server has not been alerting you to the fact that zero logs have been restored since your consultant set this up in November 2018. I believe I'll be starting over. Thank you for the answer.